# Write data from rails to S3 line by line or once as a larger whole?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, amazon-s3, filesystems

I have a script which takes a file, manipulates some data, and writes an output .csv file.  The .csv file should be available for the user to view and download.  This is a rails app on heroku with S3.

Right now the script writes a hard coded local filesystem output file "line by line".  When I integrate this script with rails, heroku, & amazon S3 do I have to restructure the script to build an array line by line in the controller and write it once as a whole to S3?  or do I continue writing to S3 line by line as I do locally?

It appears like I need to build an array in the controller and post to S3?  Then a controller 'show' action would reference the file for instance variables used in the view.  Almost makes me wonder if the user can just make the csv on the client side and never have to make a file to store on S3?  Is this a job for AJAX?

I'm looking at the aws-sdk now to access the file as I would any other file on my local system.

rough example of the as is, write per line code:

```
file_in.each_line do |line|
    #some line manipulation
    file_out << output
end
```

Easy to switch this code to build an array and then write once... I originally wrote it line by line so I don't have the whole file in a large array...

```
file_in.each_line do |line|
    #some line manipulation
    @array.push(output)
end
file_out << @array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 is not a local filesystem - you need to build the file locally and then send it to S3 (there is software that will make s3 look like a filesystem although I don't know whether you can get that to run on heroku).

If your file is large you can do multipart uploads, but each part (other than the last) must be at least 5MB.